# Software to easily toggle between normal contrast/low contrast

Tags: windows-10, dark-theme

I use a windows 10 tablet and I use a dark theme before bedtime. Inevitably during my browsing, I might want to look at an image that has some bright colors, which will hurt my eyes a bit because my eyes get adjusted to the dark theme.

The solution would seem to be to decrease the contrast, but I don't want to have to manually adjust the screen contrast each time. It would be great if there was some app that appeared in the tray in the bottom right that would let me toggle between normal contrast (out of the box contrast) and a low contrast mode that would make even bright images seem darker. With just a click or two.

What's my best bet?

Answer (score 1):

#### How can I easily toggle between normal contrast/low contrast

You can use [f.lux](https://justgetflux.com/):

> f.lux makes your computer screen look like the room you're in, all the time. When the sun sets, it makes your computer look like your indoor lights. In the morning, it makes things look like sunlight again.
>
> Tell f.lux what kind of lighting you have, and where you live. Then forget about it. f.lux will do the rest, automatically.

At night time you can quickly toggle between different lighting settings (right click tray icon > select "Lighting at night" and select a preset).

> What are the PC presets in Kelvin?
>
> - Ember: 1200K
> - Candle: 1900K
> - Warm Incandescent: 2300K
> - Incandescent: 2700K
> - Halogen: 3400K
> - Fluorescent: 4200K
> - Daylight: 5500K

Source [f.lux support](https://justgetflux.com/faq.html)

Unfortunately my screen shot program does not capture the different display modes.